# How can I use a Jenkins plugin inside a class?

Tags: class, jenkins, groovy, plugins, call

I am pretty new to Jenkins/Groovy to please bear with me here.

I am working with a DSL inside a pipeline groovy script. The DSL instantiates a custom class that tries to use Jenkins plugins. I keep getting errors that appear as if the system is trying to access the plugins as direct members of the class...?

**Jenkins Job: Pipeline Script**

```
@Library('lib-jenkins-util@branchname') _  // contains dsl.groovy

dsl {
    x = 'value'
}
```

**File: dsl.groovy**

```
def call(body) {
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()

node('node-name') {

    stage('Stage 1') {
        def f = new Foo()
    }

}
```

**File: Foo.groovy**

```
class Foo implements Serializable {
    Foo() {
        // fails below
        sh "curl http://our-jenkins-server/xxx/api/json -user username:apitoken -o output.json"
        json = readJSON file: output.json
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method:
>   com.xxx.Foo.sh() is
>   applicable for argument types:
>   (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [curl http://our-jenkins-server/xxx/api/json -user username:apitoken -o output.json]

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing? Is it not possible to directly call plugins from within a custom class?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I found the answer: plugins such as `sh`, `httpResponse`, `readJSON`, etc are part of the Pipeline, so you have to send the **pipeline context** to your class in order to be able to use it.

I also had to move calls that used the Pipeline context to their own methods instead of inside the constructor to avoid a `CpsCallableInvocation` issue that caused the build to fail.

**File: dls.groovy**

```
def call(body) {
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()

node('node-name') {
    stage('Stage 1') {
        def f = new Foo(this)  // send pipeline context to class
    }
}
```

**File: Foo.groovy**

```
class Foo implements Serializable {
    def context

    Foo(context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    def doTheThing() {
        this.context.sh "curl http://our-jenkins-server/xxx/api/json -user username:apitoken -o output.json"
        def json = this.context.readJSON file: output.json
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps